# When I post a reply with a form i get "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

i have a post and a form to reply. when i submit the form the url is this "http://forum.dev/threads/POST?_token=FIjEkUuNOyFfx8abaiIMEbep2VO1SXYk2b6hqzfT&body=something"

but the page gives me this:
[image: sorry the page you are looking for could not be found]

my view is:

```
 @if (auth()->check())
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <form action="POST" action="{{ $thread->path() . '/replies' }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="body" id="body" class="form-control" placeholder="Have something to say?" rows="5"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Post</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
```

my controller is:

```
public function store(Thread $thread)
{
    $thread->addReply([
        'body' => request('body'),
        'user_id' => auth()->id()
    ]);

    return back();
}
```

my thread model is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thread extends Model
{
protected $guarded = [];

public function path()
{
    return '/threads/' . $this->id;
}

public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
}

public function creator()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function addReply($reply)
{
    $this->replies()->create($reply);
}
}
```

if i am forgetting something please let me know!
any help would be very appreciated!
Thank you very much!

Comment: add your route definition. are you using implicit or explicit model binding? did you set the correct route key name on the model?   you are passing an `id` when building the URL but the URL you have pasted you are trying doesn't seem to be using an `id` .. it is also submitting via method GET not POST it would seem based on your URL

Comment: `<form action="POST" action="{{ $thread->path() . '/replies' }}">` - you specified `action` twice, but actually meant `method` in the first instance. The browser, due to HTML parsing and error handing rules, ignored the second occurrence of the same attribute. Therefor, the request was send to `http://forum.dev/threads/POST`, and the form data appended in the query string, because the method was set to GET, default for the missign `method` attribute. Duh. :)

Comment: Yes thank you @CBroe i totally missed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a GET request. You need to make POST request.  So check for html syntax. Also check for another form that overrides this form.
I am sure about my answer, but with post method you wont be able to see sent data in URL.